# Find weekday of date

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time

I need to find the weekday of the 28th day of the year and month given. For test data:

```
1999-5
1998-6
```

I expect:

```
MONDAY
TUESDAY
```

Below is my solution:

```
date = []
2.times {date << gets.chop.split("-")}
for i in 0..1 do
  time = Time.new(date[i][0], date[i][1], 28)
  puts time.strftime("%^A")   # get Weekday
end
```

It returns

```
FRIDAY
SUNDAY
```

What I'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: task was originally for java and I do it on ruby, may be this is clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working. May 28th, 1999 was a Friday.

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_1999